# How to copy a value and paste it to another sheet based on a criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a value and paste it to another sheet based on criteria of a cell value by iterating a range.

**Criteria**: if a cell value of a row of the range has "new", copy a value of a different cell of the same row.
For example, look for 'new' in `NewProd` column, and if found, copy the values of `Product` *AND* `Desc` columns(the values of the two columns) of the same row.

The table looks like this:
[Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6WMT.png)

**Problem**: when pasting the copied value, the first iteration gets the correct value(the yellow row value), however the second iteration gets the same value as the first one. It should be the green row value in the image, but gets the yellow row value.

**My code**:

```
Sub AddNewProd()

Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim lr As Long
Dim lr2 As Long
Dim c As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim prd As Range
Dim desc As Range

Set tbl = Sheets("sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
'Count the number of the row of the NewProd column.
lr = tbl.Range.Rows.Count
lr2 = Sheets("sheet2").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Sheets("sheet1").Select

Set rng = Sheets("sheet1").Range("AS2:AS" & lr)
Set prd = tbl.ListColumns("Product").DataBodyRange
Set desc = tbl.ListColumns("Desc").DataBodyRange

For Each c In rng
    If c = "New" Then
    prd.Offset(1).Resize(1, 2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Sheets("sheet2").Select
    Range("A" & lr2 + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    lr2 = Sheets("sheet2").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End If
    Next c
 End Sub
```

Comment: It stops iterating because you have ``Exit Sub`` the first time it finds "New". Try stepping through the code and work out what each step is doing. Check each value as it's goes and work out if it's the correct one. These are some basics of debugging code.

Comment: @ACCtionMan I removed `Exit Sub` and iteration works fine, but the second iteration does not get the value as the same value as the first iteration. I will try debugging. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is `mtrl`, I don't see it set.

Comment: Are you using a listobject on sheet2 as well?

Comment: @Davesexcel I fixed the code.

Comment: @Ike No, Sheet2 is where the copied values are pasted. and I want to paste the value below the last row, so lr2 is to count the number of the rows on sheet2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Office 365 then you can use the new `Filter`-Function:

[image]

If you want to do it by VBA I suggest the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum en_TableColumns
    col_Product = 1
    col_Desc = 2
    col_isNew = 3
End Enum

Private Const ProductStatusToCopy As String = "new"

Sub copyNewProducts()

Dim loSource As ListObject
Set loSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")

'get source data into array
Dim arrSourceData As Variant
arrSourceData = loSource.DataBodyRange.Value

Dim cntNewProducts As Long
cntNewProducts = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(loSource.ListColumns(col_isNew).DataBodyRange, ProductStatusToCopy)

Dim arrTargetData As Variant
ReDim arrTargetData(1 To cntNewProducts, 1 To 2)

Dim rSourceRow As Long, rTargetRow As Long
For rSourceRow = 1 To UBound(arrSourceData, 1)
    If arrSourceData(rSourceRow, col_isNew) = ProductStatusToCopy Then
        'copy product data to target array if new
        rTargetRow = rTargetRow + 1
        arrTargetData(rTargetRow, col_Product) = arrSourceData(rSourceRow, col_Product)
        arrTargetData(rTargetRow, col_Desc) = arrSourceData(rSourceRow, col_Desc)
    End If
Next
   
'write target array to sheet2 - writing an array to a sheet is much, much faster than writing cell per cell
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 1)
    .CurrentRegion.Clear
    .Resize(cntNewProducts, 2).Value = arrTargetData
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I am sorry for the late response. Thank you so much for your help. I do not use Office 365, so I used your code and executed it. but I got an error on `arrTargetData(r, col_Product) = arrSourceData(r, col_Product)`, the error is `Subscript out of range`. Also, `col_Product` had a wrong value. The value is associated with the value "exist" on the New Product column.

Comment: I am trying to understand your code. What does `r` do ?? I think the code gets the wrong row value, and am thinking why.

Comment: There was indeed an error - sorry. I corrected the code plus renamend i and r to be more "understandable" - they are the row-counters for source- and target-array What do you mean by col_Product hat a wrong value?

Comment: `col_Product ` had `Prod1`. It should ignore rows with "exist" on New product column. It is supposed to have Prod2. Thank you for the update. I am going to try it.